# Use older version of jHipster

Tags: yeoman, jhipster

I have different projects using jHipster (which is an absolutely awesome project!!!). 
My problem is that I have already made important changes on some projects created with earlier version and I don't want to upgrade to the latest version.

Is there any way to set the version while using the generator ?

What I'm looking for is something like that :

```
yo jhispter:entity foo -v 1.2.0
```

when I want to use the version 1.2.0 to generate the entity.

Does something like that exist ? If no, how to manage different versions of the generator ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After more research on the subject it looks like you need to install an older version to switch version.

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@1.2.0
```